# Is there a multi-sub-website/group handling CMS?

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

I'm looking for a good, easy to use and manage, free Content Management System that is built for (or can handle) multiple sub websites, or groups. Something like Drupal's Organic Groups functionality, except I don't want Drupal. My goal is to create a main site mydomain.com that sells websites (for guilds) at guildname.mydomain.com.

Thanks to Alerty for recommending the SilverStripe CMS, which works great! Although I've marked this as answered, if anybody else knows of any other ones, that would be great to know to.

EDIT: preferably something that won't requite multiple installs? I want any subscriber to the main site to be able to just pay $n and then click a "start site" button, which would automatically set up a new group/sub-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [SilverStripe CMS](http://silverstripe.org). You can view a [demo](http://demo.silverstripe.org/) of the CMS's UI on their site.

You will have to follow the steps at this website to enable the functionality you wish to have: http://internet.geek.nz/46/how-to-use-silverstripe-to-manage-multiple-sites/.

One last thing, SilverStripe CMS allows the development and integration of [extensions](http://www.silverstripe.org/extending-silverstripe/) (modules, theme and widgets). Therefore, you can implement new features as long as you are ready to get your hands dirty. `;)`

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Wait a second, would that need multiple installs of Silver Stripe?

Comment: Nope, you don't need multiple installs. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Network of sites using [WordPress' Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) feature.

Answer (score -1):

I good CMS for this is [Drupal.](http://drupal.org/)

[Here](http://drupal.org/node/43816) you can check some info on multi site implementation.

Comment: Original poster said they want something like Drupal's Organic Groups functionality, but not Drupal.